# Dynamically created getmdl-select field's drop down window doesn't close on click of an item

Tags: javascript, jquery, material-design-lite

Code for creation of input text element with getmdl-select class dynamically.
Code Snippet

```
<div id="project-details">
<div id='project-type' class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label getmdl-select">
    <input id="mainText" class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text"  readonly tabIndex="-1">
    <label for="mainText">
        <i class="mdl-icon-toggle__label material-icons">keyboard_arrow_down</i>
    </label>
    <label for="mainText" class="mdl-textfield__label">Project Type</label>
    <ul for="mainText" class="mdl-menu mdl-menu--bottom-left mdl-js-menu">
        <li class="mdl-menu__item">Enhancements</li>
    </ul>
</div>
</div>

Div with id "project-details" is created along with the form(static).

Below code dynamically creates the Div with id "project-type" and its child elements.

JavaScript Code
---------------

var project_type = document.createElement('div');
project_type.id="project-type";
project_type.className="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label getmdl-select";
componentHandler.upgradeElement(project_type);
document.getElementById('project-details').appendChild(project_type);

//Input element
var mainText = document.createElement('input');
mainText.class="mdl-textfield__input"
mainText.type="text";
mainText.className="mdl-textfield__input";
mainText.id="mainText";
mainText.tabIndex="-1";
mainText.readOnly=true;
componentHandler.upgradeElement(mainText);
document.getElementById('project-type').appendChild(mainText);

//Adding Label and i tag
var lbl_project_type = document.createElement('label');
lbl_project_type.setAttribute("for","mainText");
lbl_project_type.id="lbl-mainText";
componentHandler.upgradeElement(lbl_project_type);
document.getElementById('project-type').appendChild(lbl_project_type);

var i_lbl_project_type= document.createElement('i');
i_lbl_project_type.className="mdl-icon-toggle__label material-icons";
i_lbl_project_type.innerHTML = "keyboard_arrow_down";
componentHandler.upgradeElement(i_lbl_project_type);
document.getElementById('lbl-mainText').appendChild(i_lbl_project_type);    

//Adding label for ul
var lbl_ul_project_type = document.createElement('label');
lbl_ul_project_type.setAttribute("for","mainText");
lbl_ul_project_type.id="lbl-ul";
lbl_ul_project_type.className="mdl-textfield__label";
lbl_ul_project_type.innerHTML="Project Type";
document.getElementById('project-type').appendChild(lbl_ul_project_type);
componentHandler.upgradeElement(lbl_ul_project_type);

//Add ul 
var ul_project_type = document.createElement('ul');
ul_project_type.setAttribute("id","ul-project-type");
ul_project_type.setAttribute("for","mainText");
ul_project_type.className="mdl-menu mdl-menu--bottom-left mdl-js-menu";
document.getElementById('project-type').appendChild(ul_project_type);
componentHandler.upgradeElement(ul_project_type);


//Add li
var li = document.createElement('li');
li.id = "li-ul-project-type";
li.className ="mdl-menu__item";
li.innerHTML = "Enhancement";
li.setAttribute("tabindex", "-1");
document.getElementById('ul-project-type').appendChild(li);
componentHandler.upgradeElement(li);

componentHandler.upgradeElement(project_type);

//Trigger init function of getmdlSelect
getmdlSelect.init(".getmdl-select");
componentHandler.upgradeDom();

//trigger the javascript to bind the event
$.ajax ({
    url: "http://localhost:8000/js/getmdl-select.min.js",
    dataType: "script",
    success: console.log('success')
})
```

Issue: The dropdown window doesn't close after i select the "li item"(li value= "Enhancement"). I tried to manually trigger the javascript, called getmdlSelect.init(".getmdl-select"); but no luck.

The javascript code is triggered on click of a button.

I need help to fix this issue. Thanks.

Comment: This code is very hard to read for anyone else beside the author (variable names aren't clear). Try re-writing this so people will be able to try and help you. Also, if you include a lot of code, it is better to add some sort of example snippet(in the toolbar when you edit).

Comment: Hi @Thatkookooguy, I did modify variable names and added code snippet. Hope this helps to understand the code. Tks.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need upgrade all elements by this line `componentHandler.upgradeElement(element);`. Removed it from everywhere except the last call. 
It's enough to write `getmdlSelect.init(".getmdl-select"); componentHandler.upgradeDom();` 
in the end of your code.

Here your example in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/franckevva/fj1uw3ft/)

Answer (score 1):

You can always add `componentHandler.upgradeAllRegistered()` at the end of your updates